# django - setting cookie for session on mobile

Tags: django, cookies, session-cookies

I am using

```
response.set_cookie(key, value, max_age=None, domain=domain, secure=None)
```

This works well on a web browser as max_age=None sets the cookie as long as the browser is open. But on iOS or Android, the browser never actually closes, but keeps running in the background. Thus, the cookie remains set even when i exit the browser. It only works if I manually go and kill the browser.
Any idea how to set the cookie for a session on mobile devices?